# How do I direct the routing of a form to a controller other than the one associated with the model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bit of a RoR newbee.  I would like to display a model attribute on a form, provide the capability for the user to change its value and 'submit' the form.  I want to route the form to a controller that is not the 'base' controller for the class to which the attribute belongs and have the 'secondary' controller update the attribute in the DB.  Here's the code for the form:

```
<h1>Edit Number of Current Calls</h1>
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Number of Current Calls:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :current_call_count %>
  </div>
  <%= button_to 'Update In', { :controller => "client_profiles", :action => "update" }, :method => :put %>
<% end %>

<%= button_to 'Update Out 1', { :controller => "client_profiles", :action => "update" }, :method => :put %>

<%= button_to 'Update Out 2', { :controller => "client_profiles", :action => "update", :client => {:current_call_count => @client.current_call_count} }, :method => :put %>
```

If the user 'clicks' the 'Update In' button their submission is routed to the "clients" controller and the attribute is updated in the DB.

If the user clicks either the 'Update Out 1' or 'Update Out 2' buttons their submission is routed to the "client_profiles" controller, but the attribute is not updated.  Here's the relevant code in the "client_profiles" controller:

```
    def update
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
      @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
      redirect_to show_phone_client_profile_path(@client)
    end
```

How can I route the "Update In" submission to the "client_profiles" controller?

How do I capture the user entered value in an 'Update Out' button?

Why does the location of the "button_to code" change the routing that is directed in the button_to options?

I really want to update just the one attribute from a form that displays data for several models.  What's the right Rails Way?

Comment: There's a lot going on here, and several things that need to be changed.  Perhaps you can just describe in 1 or 2 sentences the functionality that you want?

Answer (score 0):

If your view has multiple models and you want to update particular model then you can pass that particular model or may be just id and changed attributes through url in params hash. But it mostly depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. May be you should rewrite your exact problem to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this has more than one thing going on, first let's take a look at one of the simpler questions:

> Why does the location of the "button_to code" change the routing that is directed in the button_to options?

This is simple: it's because the `Update In` button is inside your form block. So it's just submitting the form to the action specified in the first line of your `form_for` block.

The first thing to realize here is that the action of a form's submission is not dependent on the submit button, it's dependent on the properties of the form itself. If you examine your rendered HTML, you'll see the `<form>` element has an attribute called `action`. When the submit button inside the form is clicked, it will submit the form data to the location specified in that action. In this case, the `action` property is derived from the `form_for` block's passed-in object (`@client`) using the Rails assumed resourceful routing, because convention-before-configuration.

If **I** wanted to be able to submit a form to multiple locations, I'd use jQuery and AJAX post.

What's basically happening is that your `Update Out` buttons aren't attached to the form, so they're not submitting the form's data. You need to somehow relate the two, and since forms natively really only support one submit function, you'd basically have to do it in JavaScript.

I won't go into attempting to document the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), but what you'd basically be looking to do here is to register a jQuery POST callback for each of your buttons that will submit the form data to the relevant page.

Comment: Thank you for the insight into the convention for form submission.  You led me to a solution that puts the logic of what to do after the form is submitted in the controller where it belongs!